# Location to store temporary files created by a WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, temporary-files

How can I get the folder in which a C# WinForms executable file is located?

My program generates some temporary files and I am wondering if the location of the executable is a safe location to place them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the files are just temp files, you should probably be using the following:

```
string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

That will give you the current user's temp folder. This is probably a safer bet then trying to write them into the exe's current folder.

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx

Comment: The Program Files folder is not writable by standard users - it's never safe to assume that the exe's folder is writable.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the directory derived from `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`:

```
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

If you just want to generate temporary files you can also use `Path.GetTempFileName()` to get the file names.

Answer (score 1):

It's preferred to store temp files in temp directories, (as [Dan Rigby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53777/dan-rigby) said)

```
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

But if you still want to save temp files in directory from where application is running then you can simply use `Application.StartupPath` for WinForms applications,

```
string directory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
```